# Client Side Printing using IE11 using ExecWB and Javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, asp-classic, activex

I'm trying to use client side printing using the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doprint() {
        self.blur();
        var WebBrowser = '<OBJECT ID="WebBrowserObject" WIDTH=0 HEIGHT=0 CLASSID="CLSID:8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2"></OBJECT>';
        document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', WebBrowser);
        WebBrowserObject.ExecWB(6, 2);
        WebBrowserObject.outerHTML = "";
    }
</script>
```

When I review the error while debugging in IE I get the following error: "Member Not Found" at the WebBrowserObject.ExecWB(6,2)

The same code works fine on other Windows workstations running IE11 and Windows 7.  (Note: I'm running Windows 8)

Answer (score 1):

Ok found the problem, the code is fine. The problem was I had to trust the site within Internet Explorer. The Custom Level that allows ActiveX printing was not associated to the correct site which caused the "Member Not Found" error.